# How to get selected radio button in controller

Tags: sapui5

I have a view ..

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="quiz.controller.View1"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  displayBlock="true"
>
  <App>
    <Page title="{i18n>title}">
      <Text text="{questions>/question/text}" />
      <RadioButtonGroup columns="5">
        <RadioButton id="RB3-1" text="{questions>/question/option/1}" />
        <RadioButton id="RB3-2" text="{questions>/question/option/2}" />
        <RadioButton id="RB3-3" text="{questions>/question/option/3}" />
        <RadioButton id="RB3-4" text="{questions>/question/option/4}" />
      </RadioButtonGroup>
      <Button text="Default" press=".onPress" />
    </Page>
  </App>
</mvc:View>
```

.. in which there is a radio button group with four options. I was looking to display one of the radio buttons as selected as soon as the button is pressed.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/MessageToast"
], function(Controller, MessageToast) {
  "use strict";

  return Controller.extend("quiz.controller.View1", {
    onPress: function(evt) {
      // MessageToast.show(); over here I want to show the button which is pressed
    }
  });
});
```

How do I do it? I tried by using `document.getElementById()` but it's not working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give id to:

```
<RadioButtonGroup id="IDRadioButtonGroup"
```

and access it in the button method:

```
onPress:  function(){
   var oIDRadioButtonGroup = this.byId("IDRadioButtonGroup");
   console.log("BUTTON: " + oIDRadioButtonGroup.getSelectedButton());
}
```

Here is [example](http://jsbin.com/yuvuzegude/1/edit?html,output).